# wrap() a element children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i can wrap an entire li-element in an ordered list with a link at the moment:

```
$(e).wrap('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/xyz/\');return false;"></a>');
```

HTML construct:

```
<li class="">
    <img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx">
</li>
<li class="">
    <img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx">
</li>
<a onclick="window.open('/something/');return false;" href="#">
    <li class="">
        <img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx">
    </li>
</a>
```

How can i manage it to wrap the link just around the image itself and not around the whole list-element?

Comment: May I have the desired outcome?

Comment: what i need is a linked imagetag inside my desired list-element:

    <li class="">
        <a onclick="window.open('/something/');return false;" href="#"><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></a>
    </li>

Comment: you said "i've got in $(e).html my desired image-tag" so what's e?
`var e=$('<ul><li class=""><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></li><li class=""><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></li></ul>');` right?

Comment: e is the whole list-item with my desired image-tag within:

<li class=""><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></li>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#ul li img").wrap('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/xyz/\');return false;"></a>');
```

Comment: i've got in $(e).html my desired image-tag:

console.log('e is: ' + $(e).html());

But the try of

$(e).find('img').wrap('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/xyz/\');return false;"></a>');

sets the link just right before the image...weird, isn't it?

my other one:

(e.html()).wrap('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/plus/\');return false;"></a>');

does nothing..

Comment: @michbeck Where exactly you want to wrap it? on document load or in any event?

Comment: it's inside an image slider script where the images are loaded in the DOM inside list-itmes. if you you are interested in the whole function i could send it via email or skype

Comment: @michbeck yes you can send, you can find contacts on my profile

Answer (score 0):

the only successfull approach:

```
var myImg = $(e).html();
$(e).html('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/xyz/\');return false;">' + myImg + '</a>‘);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want. The key is you should wrap the `e` before making it a jQuery object. Then `$e.html()`is what you want.

```
var e = '<li class=""><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></li><li class=""><img src="http://img.example.com/images/bdb/2474566/600x338.jpg" class="xx"></li>';
var $e = $("<ul>"+e+"</ul>");
$new.find("img").wrap('<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/xyz/\');return false;"></a>');
```

Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2e6hb/1/).